# How to highlight unused Python imports in VIM

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-python

I want to highlight unused Python imports as Python syntax errors.

For example, I sometimes forget to remove some packages used for debugging such as `time`, `ipdb`. It would be great to see warnings or even errors for the unused imports.

I use `Syntastic` plugin, but it does not highligh the unused imports or I don't know how to configure it. I have this `Syntastic` setting set:

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['python', 'flake8']
```

Comment: You would need to configure a tool that checks for unused imports and integrate it syntastic. According to [this](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/error-codes.html) flake8 should provide such detection

Comment: You are right, the checks for unused imports are part of `flake8`. The problem was, that I forgot to install `flake8` package into my virtual environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flake8 already supports [checking for unused imports](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/error-codes.html) and is integrated with Syntastic.

Python developers should make sure to install flake8 into their user or virtual environment.